# How to make a CSV file to be persistent in memory for a Website to be used

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have written an ASP.NET 2.0 Website to be used as an suggestion service page. 
Every time someone types a letter in a textbox, the searched text is sent to the ASP.NET page asynchronously and searched in a CSV file to get back the data(matching suggestions).

I'm using File.ReadAllLines() method to read the CSV file into an Array for further processing.

The page is somewhat working fine. However, since this page is hit for every character we are typing, the service is slow in responding.

Are there any ways through which can I keep the CSV file always available in memory so that each request may not require to read the CSV file?

The CSV file is considerably huge, spanning to 100K+ lines.

Any suggestion would surely help me a lot.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @DrewKennedy You misunderstood .. its server side code needed here.

Answer (score 2):

If you store it in [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll only need to read it the once, but this would be per HTTP session.

If you need the same file for different users, consider using [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx) which is pretty much the same logic.

If you need to expire it, look into [Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), its a little more difficult for me to air code an example up, but follows the same principles but gives you control when it can expire. The MSDN article I linked to has detail.

---

### Session Example

Setting in session (assuming you load your csv into a string):

```
Session["CSVContent"] = csv;
```

Reading from session:

```
var myCsv = (string)Session["CSVContent"];
```

E.g.

```
string myCsv;
if (Session["CSVContent"] == null)
{
   // read csv here into a variable called csv then:
   Session["CSVContent"] = csv;
   myCsv = csv;
}
else
{
    myCsv = (string)Session["CSVContent"];
}

// Process myCsv
```

---

### Application Example

Setting in Application (assuming you load your csv into a string):

```
Application["CSVContent"] = csv;
```

Reading from Application:

```
var myCsv = (string)Application["CSVContent"];
```

E.g.

```
string myCsv;
if (Application["CSVContent"] == null)
{
   // read csv here into a variable called csv then:
   Application["CSVContent"] = csv;
   myCsv = csv;
}
else
{
    myCsv = (string)Application["CSVContent"];
}

// Process myCsv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Suggestions Nikolai. I think the Application object would suit fine for my requirement. I will give it a try and will post the results here.